# Run single test using Intellij linking to Suites class from scala test

Tags: scala, unit-testing, automated-tests, sbt, scalatest

Hi everybody I have these suites:

```
@DoNotDiscover
class Suite1 extends FunSuite with Suite{
          test("Test1"){
            println("Running test1")
            println("Using data inserted by MasterDataSuite")
          }
}

@DoNotDiscover
class Suite2 extends FunSuite with Suite{
          test("Test2"){
             println("Running test2")
             println("Using data inserted by MasterDataSuite")

          }
}

class MasterDataSuite extends Suites(new Suite1,new Suite2) with BeforeAndAfterAllConfigMap {
     override def beforeAll(configMap: ConfigMap) {
        //inserting in DB
     }

     override def afterAll(configMap: ConfigMap) {
        //deleting in DB
     }
}
```

If I run by command line, the data necessary in MasterData class is inserted, all good so far.
My big problem is if I want to run a single test in Suite1 or Suite2 the test will always fail because it can not find the data necessary to run successfully (this data should be inserted by beforeAll method). I am not sure if I need to set up something in Intellij, or I need to set up something from code or If it is possible.
Quick notes:

1. Why use that instead of before and after per Suite?: A: Because There are hundreds of tests that already exist in the project. Then is so long check test by test to guarantee correct data per Suite.
2. That works in the pipeline and by command line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide the version of the dependencies used. Thank you

Comment: libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest"                 %% "scalatest"              % "3.0.5"

Comment: Works correct for me with IntelliJ IDEA v2020.2 (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/). Can you please check if the behaviour is correct for you with this version? If not, please share the screenshot of the run configuration that is created for you.